# PHP: Get class name of passed var?

Tags: php, oop, php4, classname

I have a function that gets a class passed to it as a parameter. I would like to get the class name of the passed class as a string.

I tried putting this method in the passed class:

```
function getClassName()
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
```

but if the class is extended I assumed this would return the name of the subclass but it still returns the name of the super class which I find kind of odd.

So given a $var passed to a function as a parameter, is there a way to get a string of the class name?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php), that should be exactly what you're trying to achieve.

```
$class_name = get_class($object);
```

Answer (score 11):

Simplest way how to get Class name without namespace is:

```
$class = explode('\\', get_called_class());
echo end($class);
```

Or with preg_replace

```
echo preg_replace('/.*([\w]+)$/U', '$1', get_called_class());
```

Answer (score 1):

__ CLASS __ with return the name of the class the method is implemented in.

If you want to get the class name of an object passed then you can use:

```
get_class($param);
```

Also, if you're using PHP5 then the Reflection classes provided are also useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php):

```
$className = get_class($object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the php docs: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

```
<?php

abstract class bar {
    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump(get_class($this));
        var_dump(get_class());
    }
}

class foo extends bar {
}

new foo;

?>

The above example will output:

string(3) "foo"
string(3) "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also add a method into the passed class(es) returning this:

var_dump(get_called_class());